# WPF DataBinding between ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a question which I have trouble phrasing correctly, and thus haven't been able to find a satisfying answer yet. Perhaps someone here can point me in the right direction.

I am using MVVM in WPF to create an UML-like modeling tool. For all intents and purposes, let's stick to the UML analogy.

I basically have 4 ViewModels relevant here: The CanvasViewModel, ClassViewModel, MemberViewModel, TypeViewModel. They all implement the same interface exposing a bool Valid property.

As you may imagine, there is 1 global Canvas, n Classes on the canvas, n Members in a Class, and 1 Type per Member. It could be represented such as this:

```
Canvas
{
  Person (Class)
  {
    Age (Member)
    {
      int (Type)
    }
    Name (Member)
    {
      string (Type)
    }
  }
  House (Class)
  {
    Price (Member)
    {
      currency (Type)
    }
  }
}
```

And it realizes a picture such as this: (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/images/uml_class_diagram.jpg)

I bind the CanvasViewModel.Valid to the canvas to display a big red searching light if it is false.
I bind the ClassViewModel.Valid to the class box to do a wiggling animation if it is false.
I bind the MemberViewModel.Valid to the listview to flash red if it is false.
I bind the TypeViewModel.Valid to nothing in particular.

Of course, the Valid property is implemented pretty straightforward (code not tested):

```
// CanvasViewModel
public bool Valid { get { return Classes.All(x => x.Valid); } }

// ClassViewModel
public bool Valid { get { return Members.All(x => x.Valid); } }

// MemberViewModel
public bool Valid { get { return Type.Valid; } }
```

So the use case in this is: The user accidentally sets the TypeViewModel to "innt", which is an invalid type. I want all 4 ViewModels to then have their Valid property evaluated as false. And I want this event to propagate through all the correct ViewModels (from Type -> Member -> Class -> Canvas).

How on earth do I accomplish this without having to fiddle around everywhere in my code with horrible lines such as

```
var memberViewModel = new MemberViewModel(member);
memberViewModel.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => { if ( e.PropertyName == "Valid") OnPropertyChanged("Valid"); }
Members.Add(memberViewModel);
```

I don't want to string my functionality together like this. I prefer to have clean bindings, with clear cut entry/exit, get/set, or add/remove functions.

So yeah, not a binding between ViewModel and GUI, but a binding between ViewModels. I tried playing around with OnPropertyChanged and CoerceValue. But their purpose isn't entirely clear to me. It would appear as if in my case a Member OnPropertyChanged implementation would look like this

```
public static void OnPropertyChanged(...)
{
  MyParentClass.CoerceValue(ClassViewModel.ValidProperty);
}
```

I suppose this wouldn't be too bad, except I have no idea what responsibility CoerceValue actually has. Does the evaluation take place there? Does the property assume the return value of CoerceValue? Is it as simple as that OnPropertyChanged represents the "set" and CoerceValue represents the "get" as in a regular Property? Anyway, I didn't get it to work, so I doubt I understood its purpose correctly. All examples using OnPropertyChanged/CoerceValue basically deal with DependencyProperties in the same class anyway (never across class).

Any ideas how to solve this rather generic problem?

Cheers,

Rene

Comment: Ultimately it's all about property change notification propagation and classes subscribing to PropertyChanged events upstream and propagating them in their own PropertyChanged events to classes downstream. You can make registration reasonably elegant but there's not a simple way unless you want to constrain your design so much that you can have "one class to rule them all."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design patterns to deal with this situation are discussed pretty well [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233258/patterns-for-propagating-changes-up-an-object-model). 
In your case I like option 1, where you hold a reference to the parent object in each of the children. You would then invoke parent's property changed from the child in the property setter. It's probably the simplest solution but it does introduce the parent-child coupling but it doesn't seem like you would have the same concerns they describe with that. I would suggest passing a IValidating into the child's constructor and checking it for null in the setter. You could also look into the message bus pattern if you're using an mvvm framework

Comment: The fact that the message bus is mentioned kind of confirms my suspicion that there is no real elegant way of doing this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection and an interface (or some kind of base class). Use the base class to identify the type of object you want to set the value for and iterate down into each class. Something to the effect of:

```
   interface IValid
    {
        bool Valid { get; set; }
    }

    class Canvas : IValid, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool valid;
        public bool Valid
        {
            get { return this.valid; }
            set
            {
                this.valid = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Valid");

                this.SetPropertyValues(this);
            }
        }


        public Canvas()
        {
            this.Person = new Person();
        }

        public Person Person { get; set; }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void SetPropertyValues(IValid obj)
        {
            var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.CanRead)
                {
                    var validObject = property.GetValue(obj) as IValid;

                    if (validObject != null)
                    {
                        validObject.Valid = obj.Valid;

                        SetPropertyValues(validObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
    class Person : IValid, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool valid;
        public bool Valid
        {
            get { return this.valid; }
            set
            {
                this.valid = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Valid");
            }
        }


        public Person()
        {
            this.Age = new Age();
        }

        public Age Age { get; set; }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    class Age : IValid, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool valid;
        public bool Valid
        {
            get { return this.valid; }
            set
            {
                this.valid = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Valid");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```